# Enabling LOAD DATA local INFILE in mysql server 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Im trying to enable the load data local infile option is MySQL server 8.0 But Im not able to get this through. I have edited the config file with local_infile=ON under the [client], [mysql] under the CLIENT section & [mysqld] under the SERVER section. But after i do this and restart the server the server doesnt start and throws an error as 'Timeout expired' something like that.

What's puzzling is even i delete the local_infile=ON and save the config file. It still doesnt start the server. Luckily I had copy/pasted the original cofig file before i edited it. When i paste the original config file back , the server is able to start but still Im not able to load local data.

I'd want to import a csv with 6000 rows into my table and the Import option in workbench almost takes 30 mins to do this. There should be some way to get this worked out. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilitys to enable secure-file-priv

First option is allow file operations from every folder(where you have rights)

```
secure-file-priv = ""
```

Or define a fixed Folder from you `only` can be files loaded or stored

```
secure-file-priv = "C\temp\"
```

You **disable** the option by

```
#secure-file-priv = ""
```

Comment: Same problem, whatever I change in the config file for some reason the server does not start again, until i copy/paste the original config file. Looks like it simply is not accepting any changes made. What am i doing wrong here - @nbk

Comment: look into the error log, why it is not starting. there you find the cause. you have usually read and write rights in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

Comment: the log says server could not start due to timeout exception. Not very sure why this is happening.

Comment: Please post the log there must be more than that. The hole log between to restarts is a good start